# Data structure for dictionary with efficient querying of arbitrary positions

Tags: data-structures, dictionary, nlp, bioinformatics

Can anyone suggest an appropriate data structure to hold a dictionary that will allow me to query the presence of words (items) that have particular letters at particular positions? For example, determine which words (if any) have letters a,b,c at positions x,y,z. Insertions do not have to be particularly efficient.

This is basically the scrabble problem (I have scores associated with the letters too, but that need not concern us). I suspect bioinformaticians have studied the same problem under the guise of [sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment). What's the state of the art in terms of speed?

Comment: Is it not fast enough to just run a regex over all the words in your dictionary?

Comment: The queries are a particular type of regular expression, but we haven't established what data structure we are using for the dictionary in the first place. That is the question.

Comment: Have you benchmarked just putting everything in a dynamic array and just blasting everything with the regex you're interested in?  If that's sufficiently fast, it's probably not worth doing anything more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to build a very fast Scrabble player, you might want to look into the **[GADDAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GADDAG)** data structure, which was specifically designed for the purpose.  Essentially, the GADDAG is a compressed trie structure (specifically, it's a modified DAWG) that lets you explore outward and find all words that can be made with a certain set of letters subject to constraints about which letters of the words must be in what positions, as well as the overall lengths of the strings found.

The Wikipedia article on GADDAGs goes into more depth on the structure and links to the original paper on the subject.  You might also want to look at DAWGs as a starting point.

Hope this helps!